# How to extend the n-Queens problem to three dimensions?

Tags: java, n-queens

I am facing a problem that "How to extend the n-Queens problem to three dimensions?" I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Answer could be very long but esentially you add one more rule to the most known problem:
**height**

```
The solution is represented by a set D, if for the Cartesian product, D×D, each element ((ik, jk), (il, jl)) either satisfies all of the following rules or fails all of them.

(1) ik ≠ il (not on same column) 
(2) jk ≠ jl (not on same row) 
(3) ik + jk ≠ il + jl (not on same diagonal) 
(4) ik − jk ≠ il − jl (not on same diagonal)
```

To make it ***3d*** you add:

```
(5) ih ≠ jh (not on the same vertical plane with height h)
```

https://medium.com/@abhijith0505/the-n-queens-in-3-d-640e20130912

Comment: Don't forget about diagonals with height.